# No Metadata Classes to process. php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting No Metadata Classes to process while executing

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

The following is the output that I get,

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="message")
 */
```

No Metadata Classes to process.

Comment: can you share your configuration files detail ? Then I can give you correct solution. It is configuration issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
bin/console c:c --env=dev
bin/console c:c --env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when you have some entities wrong path in your configuration.

For example:
src/AppBundle/Entity/ 
This is your entity files path. It must be configured properly in your project.